# Nginx Proxy Rules

Tags: nginx

React app websites .
Site 1 : oldfrontend.com
Site 2 : newfrontend.com

A custom domain is setup .

- If the user hits example.com then its goes to newfrontend.com
- If the user hits example.com/da then it goes to oldfrontend.com . When this site is loading the URL gets appended from the site as example.com/dashboard.report
- So the challenege I am facing here is there are some other paths also to be configured
  /employee - but when site loads its will example.com/da/employee
  /accounts - example.com/da/account

with my current nginx rule it goes to a redirect loop

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    
    location ~ ^/(api|admin) {
        add_header X-Proxy "API";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass https://xxx....xx;
        #proxy_pass https://example.com;
    }

    # old app,
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/newfrontend;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location ^~ /da {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/oldfrontend;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
 
    location ~ ^/(employee|account) {                  #redirect loop
        alias /usr/share/nginx/oldfrontend;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Error pages                                       #redirect loop
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I am getting a redirect loop for employee & account